# Which is correct: "a same" or "the same"?

Tags: word-choice, articles

> He and I share a/the same book.

The book hasn't been mentioned before. So which one is used with "same", "a" or "the"?

Because the book hasn't been mentioned before, I want to use "a".

Because I remember that "same" is always used with "the" in front, I have to use "the".

Comment: It's more like once you thought of *that* book both of you share together, you've already been specific about *which* book you've thought of. And, because it's specific, you will want to use *"the"*.

Comment: Can "a" be used in front of "same"?

Comment: I think it's possible but in a very rare occasion. (I couldn't think of a good example now, and *a same-sex marriage* is not the case.) For ESL learners, I would say you should practically always use: *the same*.

Comment: I mean "a/the same something". "a same-sex marriage" doesn't fall into that case.

Comment: Here is a valid usage of *a same* I found in COCA: *Well, the survey is actually one that we conduct with Gallup, so partnering with Gallup we end up every month surveying over 100 -- over 1,000 investors, and it varies from month to month, so it's not **a same** segment every month.*

Comment: @Damkerng: Even if it is in COCA, I don't believe that usage is grammatical. It should be *the same*.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to specify that you share a book, the two ways to put it are:

> He and I share a book.

or the other way is:

> He and I share the same book.

*"the"* is a definite article. *"same"* too is definite. Hence the two are used together.

Answer (score 4):

Grammatically I think the adjective "same " always has "the " or "this""that"

etc.before it:

We all ordered the same thing.

He's driving back to Fairview that same night .